# Use flatMap on List[Either] in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

`Either` is right-biased ince Scala 2.12 which allows it to be used in for/yield blocks without projection just like `Option`. But apparently this isn't enough to behave like `Option` when used with `flatMap`.

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val nums = List.range(1,10)

    println(nums.flatMap(evenOption))
    println(nums.flatMap(evenEither)) // fails

  }

  def evenOption(x: Int): Option[Int]       = if (x % 2 == 0) Some(x) else None
  def evenEither(x: Int): Either[String, Int] = if (x % 2 == 0) Right(x) else Left("not even")

}
```

My minimal category theory knowledge makes me think that `Either` is not a monad and therefore this fails? Or how else can I make the example above work?

Comment: The problem might be related with the fact that Either does not extend TraversableOnce?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Either being or not being a monad. When you're executing `flatMap` method on some data structure, the function that you're passing into has to return an instance of that data structure. So when you're flatmapping over an Option, your function has to return an Option. If you're flatmapping over a Future, your function has to return a Future. The same goes with a List: flatmapping over a list has to return a List itself. So why does your `List.flatMap(Option)` work and `List.flatMap(Either)` doesn't? Because there's an implicit conversion from an Option to an Iterable (`Option.option2Iterable`), and that conversion took place in your example. There's no such conversion for the Either datatype (unless you create it yourself).

Comment: How does the for/yield do the flatmapping? For example: `for { n <- nums; x <- evenEither(n) } yield n`

Comment: Each generator (`<-`) would be translated to a `flatMap` operation, and the final `yield` would be translated to a `map` operation. For more details you should check the official docs: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html . If you'll have any further questions - feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4):

There are no implicit rules for flattening a `List[Either[String,Int]]` into a `List[Int]`, so you have to provide the means to do so.

```
nums.map(evenEither).flatten {case Right(e) => List(e)
                              case _ => List()}
```

But this can be expressed a little more directly.

```
nums.collect{case x if evenEither(x).isRight => x}
```