# Why can't a List of Eithers be flattened?

Tags: scala

When I write

```
println(List[String Either Int](Left("Boom"), Right(42)).flatten)
```

the compiler complains that

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:16: error: No implicit view available from Either[String,scala.this.Int] => collection.this.GenTraversableOnce[B].
  println(List[String Either Int](Left("Boom"), Right(42)).flatten)
                                                           ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:16: error: not enough arguments for method flatten: (implicit  asTraversable: scala.this.Function1[Either[String,scala.this.Int],collection.this.GenTraversableOnce[B]])immutable.this.List[B].
Unspecified value parameter asTraversable.
  println(List[String Either Int](Left("Boom"), Right(42)).flatten)
                                                           ^
```

And what is `B` in `GenTraversableOnce[B]` in the compiler output?

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't an implicit conversion from `Either` to `Right` or `Left`, you can't use `flatMap` (`flatten`) on a `List` of `Either`. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41705566/9297144).

---

If the idea is to get rid of `Left` elements and get what's contained in `Right` ones, then for this input:

```
val list = List[Either[String, Int]](Left("Boom"), Right(42))
```

you could call:

```
list.flatMap(_.right.toOption)
```

or:

```
list.collect{ case Right(x) => x }
```

which both produce:

```
res0: List[Int] = List(42)
```

---

Links to [Either](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.Either), [RightProjection](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.Either$$RightProjection) and [collect](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):List[B])

Comment: Thank you. I converted the `Either`s to `Option`s and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

To flatten a list, it must contain the elements that can be decomposed. For example

```
List(List(1,2,3), List(6,7,9)).flatten
```

will produce

```
List(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9) because the elements are the list themselves. This is not the case with Either because Left and Right are the collection of elements.
```

> And what is B in GenTraversableOnce[B] in the compiler output?

It represents any data structure that can be traversed. You can think of anything that supports **foreach** method